# How does one hold the motor bell still when tightening prop nuts?

Tags: motor, multirotor, brushless-motors, propellers, tools

Almost all of the brushless motors used in hobby-grade multirotors have a single threaded shaft and rely only on friction between the propeller and motor to keep the prop from slipping. This means that the nuts holding the propeller down must be tightened with considerable force.

When I try to do this, however, while I have a good grip on the nut (via a wrench), I can't hold on to the motor itself very well to keep it from spinning together with the nut, and if I try to hold on to the propeller, it cuts me with its sharp edges. **What are the available tools and/or techniques that can aid in keeping the motor still while tightening or undoing the prop nut?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You know those rubber wristbands that are given out at lots of events?

You can wrap one of those around the motor bell to get better purchase on it, and then torque down the prop nut.

There are also specialised tools to hold motor bells, such as the one pictured below which can be found [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3425525), on Thingiverse.

[image]

Comment: +1 for promoting my design:)

Comment: @MichałTrybus it’s a great design - thanks for sharing it on Thingiverse! :)

Answer (score 5):

There are commercially-available tools that are designed to grab around the bell using a rubber band, like this one:
[image: The tool]
[image: The tool in action]

However I felt that it's a fair bit too expensive for what it is.

So I made my own, molded specifically for my motors' size:
[image: My tool - open]
[image: My tool - in use]
It grabs the motor well (especially thanks to the teeth), but it's quite bulky and motor-specific, so I'm still in search of a more compact and universal solution. Also, I'm quite sure there are other tricks that people use to grab their motors that I don't know of.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to hold it with a tool, it's enough to pinch it with your fingers. Using a tool to hold it increases the risk of damaging the threads if you are not careful.

But I can understand if you want to use a tool to simplify things, and in that case the other answers are good. Just remember to be careful.

Some examples of how I like to hold:
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Well, holding the motor with one's fingers is definitely the first thing one would try. However when I tried that with my newly-built 5" quadcopter I found I can't pinch the motor hard enough with my fingers even to just be able to thread the nylock nut onto the shaft, nevermind actually tightening it agains the prop. So while your answer sounds reasonable, for me it doesn't solve the problem. If you know of some _special_ way of grabbing with your fingers that's superior to pinching, though, telling about that would be appreciated.

Comment: @FlashCactus try wrapping your index finger around the bell and pressing in with your thumb, that’s what works for me.

Comment: I've added some examples

Comment: Hey, you're using the same motors _and_ props as mine! 
Thanks, I'll try holding them that way next time.

Comment: Haha, what a conference! And remember that it gets easier the more you use the nut, since the nylon has to deform the first time.

Comment: This method has always worked for me except for very small motors. Only downside is I've cut my hands a couple times. Some brands of props are SUPER sharp!

Comment: If this doesn't work, it probably means that the hole in the prop is undersize, which causes extra stress in the hub. It's worth running a 5mm drill through the prop. Not only will the nut tighten up more easily, but the prop should last longer.

Answer (score 1):

There are also motor bell pliers available at many shops in case you don't have a printer. They are like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These beverage openers work perfectly, and are very cheap.

You can get them e.g. from [here](https://www.collectionsetc.com/products/pepsi-heritage-3-in-1-beverage-opener-with-grip).

[image]
([source](https://www.collectionsetc.com/globalassets/products/49675/49675_main_mr1k.jpg?width=462))

Comment: I got mine as a stocking stuffer, but can be found online if searching for 'pepsi heritage 3 in 1'. e.g., https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.newegg.com/amp/p/0ER-0088-00005.

Answer (score 1):

For field portable answers, shoving an asparagus rubber band either in the back of a prop wrench, or in a kit with whatever you use to hold onto trickier bells.  Dedicated tools are nice, but it's the kind of thing that even when racing, I'll seldom use a bell holding wrench, but a rubber band is always with me.